# background-image missing window.print

Tags: html, asp.net, css, background-image, printf

Background- Image is missing when i call window.print. please help me to solve this.

```
       <table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;                      background-image: url('Images/BgFaX.png');
        background-repeat: repeat" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 10px">
            </td>
        </tr>
    <Tr>
              <td>
                  sample testing
             </td>
     <tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: where is background image?

Comment: First add a background image. I can't find your background image.

Comment: background-image: url('Images/BgFaX.png');

Comment: can you add me some sample background-image:url('sampleimage.png') and show that in Window.Print?

Comment: http://browsers.about.com/od/firef2/ss/ffpagesetup_5.htm refer the above link.It is browser property.you have to set it manually.

Comment: Printing background colours and images is up to the user, not to the developer. This means, when the user prints, they can turn the function on or off at will. If you absolutely need background images printed, you should investigate something that will convert your layout to a PDF and print that (there are plugins in PHP that will help you do this.)

Answer (score 0):

By default background image and color is not printed . Please refer here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296326 . You have to enable the  setting